# Gitlab-ci How can I trigger a cleanup job only after previous stage succeeded disregarding all other stages status

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

I need to create a CI that erases the VMs that were created in the previous stage **only** if the previous stage succeeded.
if I use when: on_success - It works only if all stages passed.

stages:

- prep (2 jobs)
- build (5 jobs)
- test (5 jobs)
- cleanup

I want cleanup to work if all 5 test jobs passed even if I have a failure in a job that is in the build stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use needs keyword
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs

```yaml
vm:build:
  stage: build
  script: echo "Building vm..."

test_1:
  stage: test
  script: echo "test_1"

test_2:
  stage: test
  script: echo "test_2"

test_3:
  stage: test
  script: echo "test_3"

cleanup:
  stage: cleanup
  needs: ["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]
  script: echo "clea"
```

Comment: thank you,
it helped :)

Are there more options to do this? as the tests list will grow with time.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Use `when: on_success` should met your request.
If you have failure in build stage, test will not even executed.
Please provide your ci file for further discuss.

Comment: in the CI I have 5 build jobs
only one of the 5 has a dependency for a suite of tests, all others do not.

I build debug, release, 3 static analysis jobs
I test only the release build.